# Adicionar CSS no Registro da Grid

Tags: c#, linq, gridview

Estou tentando adicionar um negrito em um registro na grid, mas ele aparece como "`<b>Nome</b>`" e não "**Nome**" como deveria.

[image: Exemplo]

Estou fazendo isso pelo `code behind`, através de um `LINQ`

Segue meu método **exibirUltimoSorteio()**:

```
private void exibirUltimoSorteio()
{
    var apostadores = (from j in _contextEntities.TB_JOGOS
                 join s in _contextEntities.TB_SORTEIOS on j.SORT_ID equals s.SORT_ID
                 join a in _contextEntities.TB_APOSTADORES on j.APO_ID equals a.APO_ID
                 select a).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.APO_NOME).ToList();

    var tb_apostador = new List<TB_APOSTADORES>();

    tb_apostador.AddRange(apostadores.Select(apostador => new TB_APOSTADORES{
        APO_NOME = "<b>"+apostador.APO_NOME+"</b>"
    }));

    gvResultados.DataSource = tb_apostador;
    gvResultados.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No **evento** RowDataBound da sua grid, você pode usar:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
  e.Row.Cells[0].Text = decodedText;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Podes usar esta linha para colorir tua coluna (sem contar o título):

```
gvResultados.Columns[0].ItemStyle.Font.Bold = true;
```

O interessante é que é possível aplicar qualquer estilo que quiseres, basta mudar a parte  .ItemStyle.Font.Bold pela formatação que precisar.

Também acho que pode utilizar este for (que permite mais controle na hora de mudar os estilos, por linha e por coluna ):

```
for (int i = 0; i < gvResultados.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    gvResultados.Rows[i].Cells[0].Font.Bold = true;
}
```

Neste laço, a GridView é percorrida por linhas (Rows), assim, se quiser pintar as células da primeira coluna, use Cells[0], caso seja a segunda coluna, use Cells[1] e assim por diante.

Obs.: não tenho certeza se os títulos de coluna (APO_NOME) contam como Row, caso conte, use **i = 1**